# iReport: Calculation of percentage by percentage tool + Graph?

Tags: jasper-reports, report, ireport, percentage

I am trying to generate report using iReports on relational database.
I have to calculate percentage of certain data therefore I used Percentage tool in the Palette. That works perfectly fine for data that is coming in tabular form.

But now I have to generate chart for the same data as well. But that percentage is not getting reflected in graph now.

Percentage tool is generating following expression

```
new Double( $F{Totalvalue}.doubleValue() / $V{Totalvalue_SUM}.doubleValue() )
```

This expression is working fine for table format data but not for graph, I cann't understand why

Answer (score 0):

try change graph property "Evaluation Time" to value "Report'.. By default it is "Now".

That's why at the graph rendering time all the values are recalculated again.

Comment: How we need to calculate like this 10%{Total}